# Click an element on a web page

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

What I'm trying to do is click a specific element on a website which will run a javascript command. I'm not sure whether I should use a Web Browser or HTTP Web Requests. I don't need someone to code it for me, I just need to be pointed in the right direction and hopefully I will figure it out.

Maybe instead of clicking the element, I can run the javascript command?

Just tell me how I can do this and I'll research about it. I'm pretty confused right now.

I'm using the programming language vb.net.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve - programmatically click a Web Page element on a page without user interaction? Also, is this from a Windows Form application?

Comment: Yes for both questions. How would I achieve this? And can I just use run a javascript command instead of having to click a button? I just need to be pointed in the right direction on what I should use and how I should do it.

Comment: This is possible, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using WinForm WebBrowser control - take a look at [webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b1a88bz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method. It allows to execute JavaScript inside of a document, hosted in WebBroswer control.

Answer (score 1):

You can call a javascript function on click event.

For ex: on anchor tags, a href="#" onclick="SomeFunction();"

Or you can use jquery to handle click events.

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Thanks.

Comment: I'm using visual basic and I'm trying to programmatically click an element.